# Combine list with table

Tags: list-manipulation, headers-footers

I want to create a three-column table that has a list for one column. But when I do this, using `TableForm` with `TableHeadings`, the lines separating the headings from the table disappear.

For example, take the table

```
TableForm[Transpose[
   {Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}], {x, 0, 10}, {a, {1}}], 
     Table[a*x, {x, 0, 10}, {a, {5}}], 
     Table[a*x, {x, 0, 10}, {a, {10}}]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
       "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}, {"a=1", "a=5", 
       "a=10"}}]
```

This produces a neat table with the headings nicely delimited. But if I replace the first column with a list...

```
TableForm[Transpose[
   {{expr0, expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4, expr5, expr6, expr7, 
expr8, expr9, expr10}, 
     Table[a*x, {x, 0, 10}, {a, {5}}], 
     Table[a*x, {x, 0, 10}, {a, {10}}]}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
       "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}, {"list1", "a=5", 
       "a=10"}}]
```

...the delimiters disappear.

I have tried specifying each column as a list ahead of creating the table (i.e., `list1=...;list2=...;list3=...;TableForm[Transpose[Table...`), but I get the same result.

How do I retain the `TableHeadings` delimiters?

Comment: Use `{#} & /@ {expr0, expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4, expr5, expr6, expr7, 
  expr8, expr9, expr10}`.

Comment: Great. Want to post that as an answer and I'll tick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
div1 = Table[
  If[i == 2, Directive[Black, Thickness[3]], None], {i, 1, 5}];
div2 = Table[
  If[i == 2, Directive[Black, Thickness[3]], None], {i, 1, 13}];

Grid[Join[{{"", "a=1", "a=5", "a=10"}}, 
  Transpose[
   Join[{{"x=0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
      "10"}}, {Table[RandomInteger[{0, 10}], {x, 0, 10}], 
     Table[a*x /. a -> 5, {x, 0, 10}], 
     Table[a*x /. a -> 10, {x, 0, 10}]}]]], Dividers -> {div1, div2}]
```

[image]

Have fun!